# pillow OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

i am using pillow to merge some pics into one single large jpg image

here is my code

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import shutil
from time import sleep

folder_list = os.listdir()
for i in folder_list:
    if i[-3:] == '.py' or i[-3:] == 'zip' or i[-3:] == 'exe' or i[-3:] == 'jpg':
        folder_list.remove(i)
for manhwa in folder_list:
    os.chdir(manhwa)
    list_chap = os.listdir()
    cwd = os.getcwd()

    images = [Image.open(x) for x in list_chap]
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    max_width = max(widths)
    total_height = sum(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (max_width, total_height))
    x_offset = 0
    for im in images:
        new_im.paste(im, (0,x_offset))
        x_offset += im.size[1]
    os.chdir('..')
    new_im.save(f"{manhwa}.jpg")
    sleep(1)
```

but i still getting the same error over and over however i have the access to write in this directory

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\m\OnePiece\PicsMerger.py", line 28, in <module>
    new_im.save(f"{manhwa}.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\walee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2172, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\walee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 784, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0) + im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
  File "C:\Users\walee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 534, in _save
    raise OSError(f"encoder error {s} when writing image file")
OSError: encoder error -2 when writing image file
```

Comment: Can't reproduce using a minimized version of your code with Windows 10, Python 3.9.1, and Pillow 8.2.0. I don't think, that's necessarily a directory issue here. Have you tried updating your Pillow version if applicable?

Comment: yes i did 
also i have just installed pillow three days ago

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running into the max JPEG limit, 65535 pixels. Try saving as a tiff file.